# Match 2 data frames based on common rows, and preserving the order of rownames

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I need to amend the dataframe "DF1" by matching its 1st (and only) column with 2nd column of "DF2" and printing the matched column by **preserving the order of rownames** in DF1. I also need to replace the non-matching rows with 0. These are two examples of the data frames I have:

"DF1"

```
Ccd
Kkl
Sop
Mnn
Msg
Xxy
Zxz
Ccd
Msg
```

"DF2"

```
3   Ab
5   Abc
5   Ccd
9   Kkl
5   Msg
13  Sop
19  Klj
```

Code

```
read.table("a.txt")->DF1
read.table("b.txt")->DF2
colnames(DF1)<-c("b")
colnames(DF2)<-c("a", "b")
DF3 <- merge(DF1,DF2, by="b", all.x=TRUE) #
DF3$a[is.na(DF3$a)] <- 0 #substitute NA with 0
```

Output I get from above code is:

```
 b  a
Ccd  5
Ccd  5
Kkl  9
Mnn  0
Msg  5
Msg  5
Sop 13
Xxy  0
Zxz  0
```

Output I actually need is:

```
Ccd  5
Kkl  9
Sop  13
Mnn  0
Msg  5
Xxy  0
Zxz  0
Ccd  5
Msg  5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With data.table, you can do this:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df2)[setDT(df1),,on="b"][is.na(a), a:=0][]
```

Output:

```
    a   b
1:  5 Ccd
2:  9 Kkl
3: 13 Sop
4:  0 Mnn
5:  5 Msg
6:  0 Xxy
7:  0 Zxz
8:  5 Ccd
9:  5 Msg
```

Or with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(df1,df2, by="b") %>% mutate(a=if_else(is.na(a),0,as.double(a)))
```

Output:

```
     b  a
1: Ccd  5
2: Kkl  9
3: Sop 13
4: Mnn  0
5: Msg  5
6: Xxy  0
7: Zxz  0
8: Ccd  5
9: Msg  5
```

Input:

```
df1 <- structure(list(b = c("Ccd", "Kkl", "Sop", "Mnn", "Msg", "Xxy", 
"Zxz", "Ccd", "Msg")), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")

df2 <- structure(list(a = c(3L, 5L, 5L, 9L, 5L, 13L, 19L), b = c("Ab", 
"Abc", "Ccd", "Kkl", "Msg", "Sop", "Klj")), row.names = c(NA, 
-7L), class = "data.frame")
```